# audit_token_to_pid Undefined symbol

Tags: objective-c, macos

trying to use **audit_token_to_pid** in objective c code .
I have included **#import <bsm/libbsm.h>**

but when I build the project i am seeing following build error :
*Undefined symbol: _audit_token_to_pid*

may be I require some library but not sure how to resolve this  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#import` is not enough. Read [What is the difference between include and link when linking to a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562335/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-link-when-linking-to-a-library) and search for similar questions.

You have to link binary with this library:

[image]

Select your target, switch to *Build Phases* and add `libbsm` to Link Binary with Libraries section.

Or add `-l bsm` to `clang` command line options.